# Convert Iteger To String input from JTextFields

Tags: java

I am a java beginner and I am confused about why the code below won't convert my string JTextField variable into an integer. It keeps coming up as an error saying ' The method parseInt(String) in the type integer is not applicable for the argument JTextFields'.

```
JTextField input = new JTextField(15);
JButton btn = new JButton("Celsius to Farenheit");
JButton btn2 = new JButton();
JLabel label = new JLabel("No value converted", JLabel.CENTER);

public TemperatureConverter() {

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setSize(400, 100);
    setTitle("Temperature Converter");
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(true);
    getContentPane().setBackground(new java.awt.Color(78, 128, 198));



    btn2.addActionListener(this);

    add(input);
    add(btn);
    add(btn2);
    add(label);
}//end public


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


     Integer.parseInt(input); <------ this is coming up as an error
     int celsiusValue = input;


}//end actionperformed
```

Comment: Replace Integer.parseInt(input);  with Integer.parseInt(input.getText()); since Integer.parseInt requires a String parameter.

Comment: input is of type `JTextField` not `String`

Comment: The reason this question is getting downvoted is that the error message you posted explains the error pretty directly.  A very important part of coding is learning to interpret obvious error messages on your own.

"parseInt(String) can't take the argument JTextFields" is about as clearly described a compile-time error you'll ever come across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is you are trying to parse input which is instance of JTextField. You can perform parseInt() operation on only a String.

Here is the method singature of parseInt() method:

```
public static int parseInt(String s)
                throws NumberFormatException
```

To fix the issue here, you need to call JTextField's getText() method to return text inside the text field. Now call getText() method on the input and perform parseInt() operation on that returned String value to get the desired result.

Modify your actionPerformed() method like below:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int celsiusValue = Integer.parseInt(input.getText());
}
```

Refer to Java api for more details on getText() method:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText--.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Everything works fine now. :-)